# Right align text on image

Tags: java, graphics, 2d, awt, fontmetrics

```
   Graphics g = image.getGraphics(); 
     FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
      int actual_width= fm.stringWidth("My Value");
     drawString("My Value",total_width-actual_width,ypos);
    g.dispose();
    ImageIO.write(image, "bmp", new File(c:\\output.bmp));
```

How to make this **right aligned**?

**Actual Output**

[image]

**Required Output**

[image]

Output:-

```
System.out.println("total_width=" + image.getWidth() + " actual_width=" + actual_width);

    total_width=352 actual_width=46
    total_width=352 actual_width=38
    total_width=352 actual_width=68
    total_width=352 actual_width=73
    total_width=352 actual_width=36
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a small [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates a solution to your problem:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;

public class Test extends JFrame{

    public static void main(String [] args){
        new Test();
    }

    private Test(){
        final BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(300, 300, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics g = img.createGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        int total_width = img.getWidth();
        int y = 30;
        int padding = 100;

        String [] words = new String[]{"Example", "Of", "Right", "Alignment"};
        for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
            int actual_width = g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(words[i]);
            int x = total_width - actual_width - padding;
            g.drawString(words[i], x, y += 30);
        }
        g.dispose();


        setContentPane(new JPanel(){
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
            }
        });

        setSize(300,300);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: It will be centered if `image.getWidth()-(2*padding)==stringWidth`.  For better.. Well, see above.

Comment: Doesn't it make sense that right aligned would be the width of the component subtracted by the width of the text? It's primary school math.

Comment: Those images make no sense, unless your width values are wrong.

Comment: `System.out.println()` each width when painting to debug.

Comment: @paranoid-android : How can i get this output with drawstring() method, or is there any Alternate way ?

Comment: No it's perfectly possible! Put this line before the `drawString` and let me know what it prints. `System.out.println("total_width=" + total_width + " actual_width=" + actual_width);`

Comment: total_width=352 actual_width=46
total_width=352 actual_width=38
total_width=352 actual_width=68
total_width=352 actual_width=73
total_width=352 actual_width=36

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22834/discussion-between-niraj-deshmukh-and-paranoid-android)

Comment: @paranoid-android It would be handy if the code seen in the screen-shot were visible instead as (code formatted) text in your answer.

Comment: @paranoid-android  Nice!  I would up-vote, but used my turn earlier.